Parallel transport with respect to an affine linear metric field
Consider a convex open subset $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ endowed with a Riemannian metric $g$ that is affine in the Euclidean coordinates (and let's assume that $g$ is everywhere non-degenerate so that everything makes sense). Now let’s consider a straight line $\gamma(t) = p_0 + t (p_1 - p_0)$, where $p_0, p_1\in\Omega$ and $t\in[0,1]$. The parallel transport with respect to $g$ along $\gamma$ is a $g$-isometry from $T_{p_0}\Omega\cong\mathbb{R}^2$ to $T_{p_1}\Omega\cong\mathbb{R}^2$. Moreover, since $g$ is affine, along $\gamma$ we have that $g_{\gamma(t)} = (1-t)g_{\gamma(0)} + t g_{\gamma(1)}$ and so the parallel transport map will only depend on $g_{\gamma(0)}$, $g_{\gamma(1)}$, and $p_1 - p_0$. Now I would like to explicitly compute this parallel transport map.
To approach this, let's call the Euclidean coordinates $(x,y)$. Their tangent vectors form an orthonormal frame for the Euclidean metric, and we can also form a $g$ orthonormal frame $(e_1,e_2)$ and a dual frame of 1-forms $\omega_1,\omega_2$. We can compute the covariant derivative of a vector field $u=(u_1,u_2)$ written in the coefficients of the $g$ orthogonal basis as $$\nabla u = du_1\otimes e_1 + u_1\nabla e_1 + du_2\otimes e_2 + u_2\nabla e_2.$$ Now we can compute the covariant derivative of the frame using the connection 1-form $$\nabla_X e_i = \sum_{j}\omega_{ij}(X) e_j,$$ and so we have that if $u$ is parallel along $\gamma$ then $$\nabla_{\gamma'}u = du_1(\gamma')e_1 + du_2(\gamma')e_2 + \sum_{i,j}u_i\omega_{ij}(\gamma')e_j = 0.$$ At this point, I am a little bit stuck. I noticed that since $u$ is written with respect to an orthonormal frame, we see that the parallel transport along $\gamma$ just rotates the coefficient representation by some angle $\phi$. I would like an explicit formula for $\phi$ in terms of the coefficients of the symmetric positive definite matrices describing the metric at the endpoints of the curve; a procedure for computing it would also be enough.
I suspect there should be a more geometric way of computing the parallel transport with respect to an affine linear metric field over a line that is more enlightening than the approach I considered above.

For starters, your formula for the metric is not quite right. I assume you mean affine linear, also.

Ahh, thanks for the catch; I've just fixed it. And yes, I meant affine.

I suggest computing the orthonormal coframe and connection explicitly. You can certainly reduce to a horizontal path.

To write the orthonormal coframe, we can just multiply $(dx,dy)^\top$ from the right by the square root of the metric tensor. Do you know if we can obtain the orthonormal coframe from the metric tensor without taking a square root?

Also, I now think that the turning angle $\phi$ is just going to be the integral of $\omega_{12}$ along $\gamma$. Is that correct? By Cartan's structure equation it's straightforward to derive that $(\det\sqrt{g})\omega_{12} = (\partial_{v}a - \partial_{u}c)\omega_1 + (\partial_{v}b - \partial_{u}d)\omega_2$ where $\sqrt{g} = \begin{bmatrix}a & b \ c & d\end{bmatrix}$

Nope, you unfortunately cannot avoid yucky square roots and Gram-Schmidt.  But that’s why I thought it might be simpler to analyze a horizontal line segment path.

Yeah, checks out... the (affine) linearity of the metric tensor doesn't seem to simplify the parallel transport much then.

Absolutely not. I don’t have any idea what list of standard examples you’ve played with.
